# Custom properties does not show in User Profile SharePoint 2010

Tags: user-profile

Custom user profile properties does not show in User Profile (person.aspx) nor Object model SharePoint 2010. The SSP is upgraded from 2007 to 2010. The normal settings are set in central admin but only core properties shows up. Anoyne know whats wrong?

Comment: Define "show up". Are the properties present in Manage User properties?
Or is it just the values that are missing when you manage User profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. There were multiple Profile Service applications associated to the Webapp. A aervice app without the properties was set as default. Still getting used to the service app concept. The properties were missing from the profile alltogether because of this. They appeared when I set the default to be the one with the properties.